# how to pass an optional argument to Ant and run specific test case

Tags: ant, junit

I have a task in which a user might (and might not) pass an argument - a JUnit test class - to Ant via command line.
If the user pass the argument then only this specific test class will execute. 
If not, a all test classes will run i.e. "**/*.java".

How do I accomplish the condition above? I already know how to run specific test class but the conditional thing - class name passed through command line with -D vs. a predefined list (**/*.java) - eludes me.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  use some thing like this

```
    <batchtest todir="${test.results.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${tests.dir}">

            <include name="**/*${mytest}.class" if="mytest"/>
            <include name="**/*Test.class" unless="mytest"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
```

The key is the fileset becomes a function of command line argument passed

```
ant tests  -Dmytest=TestnamePattern
```